# delphi boolean procedure for enable or disable button

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to create a procedure to enable or disable button,
can i do it with a single procedure? for example like this:

```
Procedure MainForm.buttonsEnabled(boolean);
BEGIN
if result=true then
begin
button1.enabled:=True;
button2.enabled:=True;
button3.enabled:=True;
end else
begin
button1.enabled:=false;
button2.enabled:=false;
button3.enabled:=false;
end;
END;
```

and when I call the procedure to disable or enable the button i can call it like

```
buttonsEnabled:=True;// to enable button
buttonsEnabled:=False;// to disable button
```

can I do it like that?
I can't find a way to do that in the simple way

Comment: What you write ("i can call it like") is not true and your real method does not look like that. It does not compile, and you can't set a procedure to True. Please post real code.

Comment: It is idiomatic to write `if result then` rather than `if result=true then`, and your function can easily be simplified by removing the `if` and writing simple assignments, as shown in the answers below.

Comment: You should avoid `if Something = true then` because the `if` checks if the expression evaluates to `true`. So your code reads like `if ( Something = true ) is true then` ;o)

Comment: i'm sorry if my code is incomprehensible, im still a newbie..i make it just to explain what do i mean,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
procedure MainForm.buttonsEnabled(AEnabled: Boolean);
begin
  button1.Enabled := AEnabled;
  button2.Enabled := AEnabled;
  button3.Enabled := AEnabled;
end;

buttonsEnabled(True);
//buttonsEnabled(False);
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a property of the form:

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure SetButtonsEnabled(Value: Boolean);
  public // or private perhaps, depending on your usage
    property ButtonsEnabled: Boolean write SetButtonsEnabled;
  end;
```

Implement it like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.SetButtonsEnabled(Value: Boolean);
begin
  button1.Enabled := Value;
  button2.Enabled := Value;
  button3.Enabled := Value;
end;
```

And then you can use it as you intend:

```
ButtonsEnabled := SomeBooleanValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

For multi usage

First Option :

```
Procedure EnabledDisableControls(Ctrls:Array of TControl; Enabled:Boolean);
var
  C:TControl;
begin
  for C in Ctrls do
    C.Enabled:=Enabled;
end;


//calling example : 
procedure TForm1.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnabledDisableControls([Button1, Button2, Button3], false {or True});
end;
```

Second Option :
Recrusivelly (or not) enabling/disabling buttons on a Control :

```
Procedure EnableDisableButtonsOnControl(C:TControl; Enabled:Boolean; Recrusive:Boolean);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  if C is TButton {or TBitButton or anything you need} then
    C.Enabled:=Enabled
  else if C is TWinControl then
    for i := 0 to TWinControl(C).ControlCount-1 do
    begin
      if TWinControl(C).Controls[i] is TButton then
        TButton(TWinControl(C).Controls[i]).Enabled:=Enabled
      else
      if Recrusive then
        EnableDisableButtonsOnControl(TWinControl(C).Controls[i],Enabled,true);
    end;
end;

//calling example :
procedure TForm1.BtnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //disable all buttons on Form1:  
  EnableDisableButtonsOnControl(Self, false, false {or true});
  ...
  //disable all buttons on Panel1:  
  EnableDisableButtonsOnControl(Panel1, false, false {or true});
  ...
  //disable all buttons on Panel1 recursively:  
  EnableDisableButtonsOnControl(Panel1, false, true);
end;
```